# Удаленные файлы остаются в репозитории

Tags: git, bitbucket

Прошу прощения если вопрос глупый.
В моем локальном репозитории я удалил некоторые папки.
Затем выполнил git push в удаленный репозиторий. Удаленных папок больше нет в локальном репозитории зато в удаленном репозитории они почему то есть.
В чем проблема?

Comment: Как удаляли папки? ```git rm```?

Comment: нет. Просто удалил и все) Не знал что это что то меняет(

Comment: в локальном репозитории этих папок нет. Неужели нельзя никак удалить их на удаленном? Как то это странно

Comment: Через ```git rm --cache``` вычистить (если вспомнится все по памяти) или же сделать ```git reset --soft HEAD^1```, если удаление папок было последней операцией, затем удалить ненужное через ```git rm```, сделать коммит и пуш ```git push -f```

Comment: git rm удалил их локально в удаленном как были так и остались... Не думал что в гите такие проблемы с удалением...

Comment: Опишите подробно последовательность действий: как удаляли и т.д.

Comment: Вы просто удалили из папки?

Comment: просто удалил в ide ненужные папки и все